# Visual Studio + Git: Changing code in Branch#1 changes it in Branch#2

Tags: git, visual-studio

We changed from TFS to Git 1 month ago and some of the new PCs have a weird issue:

If they change code in Branch#1 and switch to Branch #2, they don't get the "Uncommitted Changes" notification. Instead it switches to Branch#2 and they have all the code from Branch#1 in Branch#2 (and Branch#3/4/5...).

That'sreally irritating. How can we fix this?

**UPDATE:**
We/They only switch/commit/pull etc. directly through Visual Studio UI. So for example if I switch from one branch to another, I just open the little dropdown below the Solution Explorer and select the branch that I want.

Comment: Please specify exactly how they are switching branches - if they are using command line, please include the complete command they are using.

Comment: I see this behavior currently when using IntelliJ, or Eclipse.  Even if the dirty files are still there after switching branches, you can always do `git reset --hard` to get everything synched up to the new branch.